# imagecreatefromjpeg issue [image doesnt show up]

Tags: php

I was trying to make a signature creator, everything seemed to be working except the image creation part, it shows up the dead image icon.

Here is the code

```
<?php
define('IP', '62.210.182.42');
include "koneksi.php";
if(isset($_GET['user']))
{
    $query = $koneksi->prepare("select * from `playerdata` where `user` = ?");
    $query->execute(array($_GET['user']));
    $data = $query->fetch();
    $font_dir = 'fonts/';
    $text = 'Undefined';
    $font = 'Transformers Movie.ttf';
    $font2 = 'pricedown bl.ttf';

    if($query->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        $type_space = imagettfbbox(25, 0, $font_dir.$font, $text);

        $image_width = abs($type_space[4] - $type_space[0]) + 20;
        $image_height = abs($type_space[5] - $type_space[1]) + 20;

        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("img/signature.jpg");

        imagesavealpha($im, true);
        imagealphablending($im, true);

        $bg = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 255, 255, 255, 127);
        $putih = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $hitam = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
        $abu = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 100, 255);
        $biru = imagecolorallocate($im, 245, 184, 0);
        imagefill($im, 0, 0, $bg);
        function CreateTitle($name = "Undefined", $title = "GG Player")
        {
            $size_title = 20;
            global $hitam, $putih, $font, $font_dir, $im, $biru, $font2;
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title, 0, 26, 30, $hitam, $font_dir.$font2, $name);
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title, 0, 27, 31, $hitam, $font_dir.$font2, $name);
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title, 0, 28, 32, $hitam, $font_dir.$font2, $name);
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title, 0, 29, 34, $hitam, $font_dir.$font2, $name);
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title, 0, 25, 29, $biru, $font_dir.$font2, $name);
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title, 0, 25, 29, $biru, $font_dir.$font2, $name);
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title-6, 0, 250, 27, $hitam, $font_dir.$font2, $title);
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title-6, 0, 251, 28, $hitam, $font_dir.$font2, $title);
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title-6, 0, 252, 29, $hitam, $font_dir.$font2, $title);
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title-6, 0, 253, 30, $hitam, $font_dir.$font2, $title);
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title-6, 0, 250, 27, $biru, $font_dir.$font2, $title);
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title-6, 0, 250, 27, $biru, $font_dir.$font2, $title);

        }

        function CreateStats($nomer = 1, $baris = 1, $name, $size_title = 18)
        {
            $width = 60;
            $height = 31;
            global $biru, $hitam, $font, $font_dir, $im, $biru;
            for($a = 1; $a < $nomer; $a++)
                $width+=19;
            for($a = 1; $a < $baris; $a++)
                $height+=130;
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title-5, 0, $height + 1, $width + 1, $hitam, $font_dir.$font, $name);
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title-5, 0, $height + 2, $width + 2, $hitam, $font_dir.$font, $name);
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title-5, 0, $height, $width, $biru, $font_dir.$font, $name);
        }

        function CreateIP($ip = IP)
        {
            $size_title = 15;
            global $biru, $hitam, $font, $font_dir, $im, $biru;
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title-5, 0, 320, 102, $hitam, $font_dir.$font, $ip);
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title-5, 0, 321, 103, $hitam, $font_dir.$font, $ip);
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title-5, 0, 322, 104, $hitam, $font_dir.$font, $ip);
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title-5, 0, 323, 105, $hitam, $font_dir.$font, $ip);
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title-5, 0, 320, 102, $biru, $font_dir.$font, $ip);
            $gambat = imagettftext($im, $size_title-5, 0, 320, 102, $biru, $font_dir.$font, $ip);
        }

        if($data['level'] == 1)
            $title = "Junior Administrator ";
        else if($data['level'] == 2)
            $title = "Junior Administrator ";
        else if($data['level'] == 3)
            $title = "Moderator";
        else if($data['level'] == 4)
            $title = "Senior Administrator ";
        else if($data['level'] == 5)
            $title = "Head Administrator ";
        else if($data['level'] == 6)
            $title = "Co-Owner ";
        else if($data['level'] == 1337)
            $title = "Owner ";
        else
            $title = "YGG Player ";

        if($data['level'] == 1)
            $title .= "Basic VIP ";
        else if($data['level'] == 2)
            $title .= "Silver VIP ";
        else if($data['level'] == 3)
            $title .= "Gold VIP ";

        if($data['YG'] == 1)
            $title .= "TG Member";
        else if($data['YG'] == 0)
            $title .= "Not TG";

        CreateTitle($data['user'], $title);
        CreateStats(1, 1, "Score : ".$data['score']);
        CreateStats(2, 1, "Money : ".$data['money']);
        CreateStats(3, 1, "Kills : ".$data['kills']);
        CreateStats(1, 2, "Deaths : ".$data['deaths']);
        $total = $data['kill'] / $data['deaths'];
        CreateStats(2, 2, "K/D Ratio : ".round($total, 1));
        CreateStats(3, 2, "Bank : ".$data['Bank']);
        CreateIP();

        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($im);
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location:signature.html");
    }
}
?>
```

How come it doesnt create the image?

I'm not a pro in this, still a newbie so pardon if i created any mistakes.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure three things first , no any kind of output is there before your header function call and your font file names are exactly what you are using , and most important gd library extension is enabled on your server..

Comment: how could i make sure gd lib extension is enabled?

Comment: <?php echo phpinfo(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has a sub problem i.e to check your gd library extension 
yo may do as follows

```
<?php echo phpinfo() ; ?>
```

Then search gd on the page  ,  you will find something like [image]

Comment: GD support is enabled in mine.

Comment: What about the file name .ttf  or .TTF . It would generate problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using *imagecopyresampled()* and *imagejpeg()* for resizing images. Only the thumbnail image was showing up, not the larger image.

My solution was to specify the sys_temp_dir in PHP.ini:
**sys_temp_dir = "c:\temp"**

If the image is large, PHP creates a temporary file. If so, the saved file inherits the *system default directory* ownership. In my case I could not access the saved file, only seeing a dead icon.